# How can I loop faster over an array using Cython?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, loops, cython

I have an optics tool in which i need to calculate a set of complex amplitudes (i.e. wavefronts) for a range of time steps and wavelengths. So essentially I have two for loops and for each item I have to call the method below.
Since the calculations take quite some time, I tried speeding everything up using Cython. This is what I have now:

```
cimport numpy as cnp
cimport cython
import numpy as np
from libc.math cimport exp, cos, sin

ctypedef cnp.complex128_t DTYPE_t

@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False) # compiler directive
@cython.wraparound(False) # compiler directive
cpdef DTYPE_t[:,:,::1] _get_input_complex_amplitudes(
                                  float time,
                                  float wavelength,
                                  double[::1] x_source_sky_coordinates,
                                  double[::1] y_source_sky_coordinates,
                                  double[::1] x_observatory_coordinates,
                                  double[::1] y_observatory_coordinates,
                                  float aperture_radius,
                                  int number_of_inputs,
                                  int grid_size,
                                  DTYPE_t[:,:,::1] out):
    cdef unsigned int ix, iy, index_input
    cdef double arg, cos_val, sin_val
    cdef double factor = 2 * 3.1415926536
    cdef DTYPE_t[:,:,::1] ou = out

    for index_input in range(number_of_inputs):
        for ix in range(grid_size):
            for iy in range(grid_size):
                arg = factor / wavelength * (
                        x_observatory_coordinates[index_input] * x_source_sky_coordinates[ix] +
                        y_observatory_coordinates[index_input] * y_source_sky_coordinates[iy])

                cos_val = cos(arg)
                sin_val = sin(arg)

                ou[index_input,ix, iy] = aperture_radius * (cos_val + 1j * sin_val)
    return ou
```

With this code, however, I was only able to achieve a speed-up of a factor of 3 and it still takes 0.4 ms to run the method once on my machine. I can not imagine that this is everything I can get out of Cython, so is there something I am missing? Usually, the array of time ranges has a length of 100 and the array of wavelengths has a length of 30, so 3000 method calls in total.

Alternatively, instead of looping over the time and wavelength ranges, I thought about rewriting the method to accept arrays and pass the time and wavelength range al at once. However, in that case, I would need to make a lot of use of `numpy.einsum()`, which, I hear, is not really suitable to be optimized using Cython.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I do anything else to speed of my method using Cython?
2. Is it computationally more sensible to pass a 2D-array instead of looping over two ranges?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know how your data are laid out in memory, but you need to be processing in that order to benefit from caching. Have you tried iterating over rows first, then over columns?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have not tried that, how would that speed up anything?

Comment: I'm no expert, and this is dated, but you'll get the idea http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/

Comment: @Phil I think you forgot to define i as an unsigned int. To get a detailed report of which lines have Python interactions and are slow, use the `-a` flag. Also iterating over 3D arrays is fairly slow, use `numpy.ravel()` to pass a flattened view and fetch it as `double[::1]` which in my experience helps out a lot.

Comment: @Phil nvm, it seems like the new Cython compiler (3.0.4) is smart enough to pick up on that. If you post a runnable example I can help you optimize it

Comment: What is the exact value for `grid_size` and `number_of_outputs`? Are the calls to the function independent? What are the compilation flags use to build the native code generated by Cython?

Comment: @OM222O Ok thanks, I try to come up with a workable example ASAP

Comment: @JérômeRichard `grid_size` is 80 and `number_of_outputs` is 4, both may vary, however. The calls to the function are independent, yes. And I'm using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to build

Comment: Just realized I posted the wrong code example, I updated it now, sorry for the troubles. It's pretty similar to the other one

Comment: Oh, indeed, the new code is completely different regarding performance. I expect the `sin` and `cos` to be the bottleneck now. The computation should mostly be done in the CPU cache. Thus it is compute bound.

Answer (score 0):

**`sin` and `cos` are generally expensive**. One reason is that there are many corner cases to consider : NaN values, infinities, sub-normal numbers. Another reason is the precision : AFAIK the function should have an error of at most 1 ULP which is very small for double-precision. If you know that there are no special values (NaN, Inf, subnormals) and performance matters more than accuracy, then you can enable the **`-ffast-math`** compiler option. This option also assume that floating-point math is associative for sake of performance. This is *quite unsafe* though so you should think twice.

You can do few simple optimisation based on math tricks that should significantly improve performance. Indeed `sin(arg)² + cos(arg)² = 1`, so `cos(arg) = +/- sqrt(1-sin(arg)²)`. The sign can be obtained from the value of a quite easily (especially if you know that `arg` is in the range `[X;X+2*pi[` since it help to avoid computing an expensive floating-point modulus). An `sqrt` is far less expensive than a `sin` function mainly because mainstream CPUs have dedicated units for that. Another optimisation is to pre-compute `factor / wavelength` : you can just use `factor` in the loop and compute it with `2 * 3.1415926536 / wavelength`. An optimizing compiler should already do the later though.

The `sin` and `cos` functions can be vectorized using **SIMD instructions**. This is hard to do manually, but there are libraries to do that like the *Intel SVML*. Some compiler and libc implementation can do it with `-ffast-math` too (e.g. GCC + recent glibc). In this code, I do not expect GCC and Clang to be able to vectorize the loop. The Intel compiler might. Numpy can use the SVML if it is installed on the machine. In this case, the idea is to use Numpy only for the sin/cos computation. SIMD instructions on a recent x86-64 CPU should make this code up to 2x-3x faster.

Another solution is to use **multiple threads**. However, the function is executed quite quickly so creating threads and waiting for them can introduce a significant performance overhead. If the function calls are independent, then it is better to do the call in parallel rather than parallelizing this function. This can be combined with the above SIMD optimizations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you make a lot of good points. I have jsut done quick check to see how long everything takes if I simply remove the cos and sin (producing jibberish) and I "Only" get another factor of 3 of increased speed.